# Debugging error in vs code when attempting to update node.js

Tags: node.js

current version of node js is v14.13.0,
when attempting to update version with command n -latest error occurs

````
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/20.6.1
mkdir: /usr/local/n: Permission denied

  Error: sudo required (or change ownership, or define N_PREFIX)```
````

Answer (score 0):

From you question what I understand is that you don't have the required permission to create directory so try to use sudo command before mkdir command like

```
`sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/n/versions/node/20.6.1`
```

or you can try below command to change the ownership of your user

```
sudo chown -R your_username:your_group /usr/local/n
```

Comment: i ran the first suggestion and tried to update node again and got ```  copying : node/20.6.1
find: /usr/local/n/versions/node/20.6.1/lib: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/n/versions/node/20.6.1/bin/node: No such file or directory
find: /usr/local/n/versions/node/20.6.1/include: No such file or directory
find: /usr/local/n/versions/node/20.6.1/share: No such file or directory
find: /usr/local/n/versions/node/20.6.1/share/man: No such file or directory
/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.0/bin/n: line 744: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory```